# I get a null object or an object with null values when passing data from an ajax call to MVC Controller

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I will eventually need this method to use an array of keyValue pares so passing in data one attribute per parameter is not going to work for me. I will need a dynamic object. however, I can't get the JSON interpretation to work.

I have a very simple ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url,
        success: doAThing
        contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data:JSON.stringfy({thing:'stuff'}), //I have tried just {thing:'stuff'}) as well.
        dataType: "json"
})
```

It goes into a controller:

```
public class THING
{
    public string thing { get; set; }
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult SetDAConfigs(THING param) {
      //do something
}
```

I have tried about 50 different configurations. I can either get a null object for "thing" or an object with null values. or a 500 error.

Can anyone tell what is going on? I suspect its an issue with the controller endpoint but I cant figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is put "param" in your json string.

so instead of handing in data'{"thing":"stuff"}' it should be '{"param":{"thing":"stuff"}}

what will happen is the controller will parse the json associate "param" and try to turn it into the Class associated with the parameter in the controller.